# Mozilla ESR executing onblur and onclick events simulteneously

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have hyperlink in a webpage, that calls a javascript function.

i have another .js file that contains validation methods,

when i provide a invalid input as per the criteria, it works for onblur,

when i provide a invalid input and hit hyperlink directly, it is not stopping for onblur to complete.

it goes further and executes.

"It is working for other browsers like Chrome, Safari and IE"

Code Sample,

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function save(){
    alert("in Save Method..")
    window.location = "https://google.co.in";
}

function isValidFraction(inputObj) {
    if(!inputObj.value.match(/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/)){
        inputObj.value="";
        //inputObj.focus();
        alert("Inavlid Float Number");      
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function isValidInteger(inputObj) {
    if(!inputObj.value.match(/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/)){
        inputObj.value="";
        //inputObj.focus();
        alert("Inavlid Integer Number");        
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>


<a href="javascript:save()"> Save </a> <br><br>
<input type="text" id="float_input" placeholder="Float Value" onblur="if(isValidFraction(this)){alert('valid.......');}">
<input type="text" id="int_input" placeholder="Int Value" onblur="if(isValidInteger(this)){alert('valid.......');}">
</html>
```

Comment: need code example

Comment: added sample code..